# iOS recorded video is not playing in android device?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

- I am using react-native camera to record video.
- Its play in iOS but not play in android
- Extension is : .mov for iOS and .mp4 for android

```js
<Video source={{uri:videoUri}} type="mp4"/>
```

Comment: Please share your js code.

Comment: npm react-native-video

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code,

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

<Video source={{uri:videoUri}} type=Platform.OS === 'ios'? "mov" : "mp4" />
```

Comment: Above code is work not for Samsung devices like J7,M30                                                         Getting the below issue whenever play the video.

error:{
   extra: -2147483648
   what: 1
}

Comment: hey, i check it, it will not work in android as the video is shotted in iphone

Comment: so u need to convert video into mp4, to convert video into mp4 use `react-native-mov-to-mp4`

Comment: Please visit at `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mov-to-mp4`

Comment: Okay i will try then let you know. Thank you

Comment: Hey you checked it.

Comment: I am not able install the package due to latest version of react native, may be they don't have support for latest version

Comment: Is there any way to convert video url, which is coming from API ?

Comment: Please visit at `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mov-to-mp4`

Comment: Example is given there.

Comment: When i install pod for iOS then shown error as: use_native_modules! skipped the react-native dependency 'react-native-mov-to-mp4'. No podspec file was found.